# Xcode 4.0.2 duplicated pulldown in Project settings -> Code Signing

Tags: xcode, code-signing, duplicates

In Xcode 4.0.2, I click on the project file to bring up the project settings

I then select either my target or my project from the left pane of the newly opened settings page

I then select the ' build settings ' tab bar, and scroll down to ' code signing '

I get

[image]

I don't understand why each entry is duplicated.  Can someone explain to me in plain English what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there's 2 sections in the Code Signing Identity window:

- Debug
- Release

It is not uncommon for a developer to have various iOS SDKs installed on their Mac - in this situation, it may be necessary for them to have a specific profile per iOS SDK version. The window you see would allow a developer to do this, for both debug and release versions of an app - be it for iOS or Mac.

Hope this helps!